# Trouble upgrading to r4.0 on ubuntu 18.0

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install r4.0 but am getting the following error message.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1.1804.0) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.3-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have followed several websites and now seem to be going round in circles.
I have added the GPG key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

added the correct depository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/'
```

From other questions here are the various outputs on my system

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ bionic-security multiverse
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
```

apt-cache policy r-base

```
r-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.3-1.1804.0
  Version table:
     4.0.3-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     3.4.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe arm64 Packages
```

apt-cache policy r-base-core

```
r-base-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.5.2-1
  Version table:
     3.5.2-1 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

grep -ir cran /etc/apt

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/jetson-ota-public.asc:iA+wBAUCXNOeqQAKCRANKW/7iA+wBDsJD/41AngqmSMkPpKpAegCpqwXvig4ZwRG
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
```

apt policy

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  Packages
     release o=NVIDIA,l=NVIDIA VisionWorks Tracking,c=
 500 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  Packages
     release o=NVIDIA,l=NVIDIA VisionWorks SFM,c=
 500 file:/var/visionworks-repo  Packages
     release o=NVIDIA,l=NVIDIA VisionWorks,c=
 500 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/t210 r32.4/main arm64 Packages
     release o=Nvidia,a=stable,n=r32.4,l=L4T Jetson T210 r32.4,c=main,b=arm64
     origin repo.download.nvidia.com
 500 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r32.4/main arm64 Packages
     release o=Nvidia,a=stable,n=r32.4,l=L4T Jetson r32.4,c=main,b=arm64
     origin repo.download.nvidia.com
 500 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89  Packages
     release o=NVIDIA,l=NVIDIA CUDA,c=
 500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     release v=18.04,o=CRAN,a=bionic-cran40,n=bionic-cran40,l=CRAN,c=
     origin cloud.r-project.org
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 100 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-backports,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 100 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-backports,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-updates,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main arm64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=arm64
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: I found [this blog post](https://rtask.thinkr.fr/installation-of-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/) to be helpful when I upgraded my R Version from 3 to 4 (albeit the post is also about upgrading Ubuntu, but I think you can just ignore that part)

Comment: Thanks. I think I have been on that website before. I followed the steps again but seem to have the same problem.

Comment: so you did do the "delete everything about the previous R version" and "remove all Ubuntu packages for R " step? And still get the "but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed" error??

Comment: Yes. Did all of that

Comment: It seems like your repository list is somehow broken (why would it otherwise try to install R 3, even though you removed all references to it ??) But I won't be able to help you with that. Best of luck.

Comment: I have the same problem. My suspicion is that the process that populates the repository with packages for arm64 has failed to push them all up there, so we're seeing r-base-dev but not its dependencies.I'm not sure who manages that; the last time I tried this before today was six months ago and there were *no* arm64 packages then.

Comment: P.S.: If the source packages are up on the repository you can compile and install them on your own machine. It's a laborious process - you have to figure out the dependency chain - but it will work.